# SQL how to extract a value from a variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to extract the value from a SQL variable and save this value in a new variable. For example, if I have the variable `@myVar`, which is storing the value 25, and I want to save this value to a new variable `@myVar1` before updating the value stored in `@myVar`to 30. I've found that simply setting `@myVar1:= @myVar` does not work as once I change the value stored in `@myVar`to 30 the `@myVar1` variable will automatically update itself to 30 as well.

I am using these variables in a SELECT statement in order to keep track of and compare values in a previous row to values in the current row.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
SELECT
CASE 
   When (@r is not null) then @myVar1:= @myVar
END, 
@myVar:= @myVar + 1
```

As you can see, `@myVar` is set to a new value every row, while `@myVar1` should only be set to the current value of `@myVar` if the condition is met, and remain storing that value until the condition is met again, regardless of any changes to the value `@myVar` is storing. So if `@myVar = 7` and `@r` is not null then `@myVar1 = 7`, but when `@myVar` will then be set to 8, `@myVar1` will also be set to 8 instead of remaining at 7 until the condition is met again.

Comment: Can you give an example of what I would do?

Comment: Honestly, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do here. What is your variable type? You need to probably give some sample data and what you are trying to do to get some help here.

Comment: Please add an example of what you want to get (input & output). Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do something like this:

```
@x_old := x;
@x := case when @r is not null then @y else @x end;
```

(If this is in a procedure, you can leave the `;` right where they are; if this is inside a query, replace them with `,`)

This way you will preserve the value of `@x` if the condition is not fulfilled

Comment: I tried something similar already, it won't work as once the case statement is fulfilled @x will now equal @y and now preserving the value of @x will just mean keeping it the same as @y

Comment: @djar As you can see, the assignment is not done inside the `case` but outside, so `@x` will only change if the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: But if the condition is fulfilled once `@x` will equal the variable `@y` and now when `@y` updates next row, `@x` will update with it instead of remaining at the value when the condition was fulfilled

Comment: @djar Then the value will change, which is what you want (as far as I understand); if you want to do something different, then please clarify your question

Comment: I want `@x` to equal the value of `@y` but I do not want `@x` to update along with at `@y`, I will try to clarify my question

Comment: Your edit will not work either: `@x` will be set to equal `@y` and `@x_old` is set to equal `@x` so  `@x_old:= @y` and when `@y` is set to a new value, `@x_old` will be set to that new value as well instead of remaining at `@y`'s original value

Comment: @djar are you trying to calculate a running total or something similar? (It looks like it) Your question is still unclear to me. Add some sample data and expected output to it